# What does "< /dev/null >& /dev/null" at the end of a command do?

Tags: linux, bash, stdio

One of the scripts I run over ssh was hanging and I found a solution for it on this site:
http://www.snailbook.com/faq/background-jobs.auto.html

The site resolves the problem by adding this to the end of the command:

```
xterm < /dev/null >& /dev/null &
```

I think I know what part of it does, but can someone help explain?

The first part:

```
# For stdin, read from /dev/null
< /dev/null
```

The second part:

```
>& /dev/null
```

What does `>&` do? I've seen `2>&1` which is direct STDERR to STDOUT, but when there are no numbers, does that mean redirect everything to `/dev/null`?

Comment: is any windows equal of this script ?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this means redirect both stdout and stderr to /dev/null.

From `info "(bash)Redirections"`:

> ### Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error
>
> Bash allows both the standard output (file descriptor 1) and the
>   standard error output (file descriptor 2) to be redirected to the file
>   whose name is the expansion of WORD with this construct.
>
> There are two formats for redirecting standard output and standard error:
>
> ```
> &>WORD
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> >&WORD
> ```
>
> Of the two forms, the first is preferred.  This is semantically
>   equivalent to
>
> ```
> >WORD 2>&1
> ```

Comment: But what is /dev/null? I'm guessing it's redirecting all output to nothing (no file)?

Answer (score 1):

With `ssh` another way (to achieve what you probably want) is to pass the `-f` flag, i.e.

```
ssh -X -f your.host.org xterm
```

Answer (score 1):

Googling for 'stream redirection >& ' will let you find 
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

which, among other things, tells you

```
  >&j

  # Redirects, by default, file descriptor 1 (stdout) to j.
  # All stdout gets sent to file pointed to by j.
```

Maybe this already helps.

Or search the help of standard unix shells, like bash, for stream redirection.

Rgds,

Thomas