# What exactly does this PHP code do? system("php ./somescript.php $something >/dev/null &");

Tags: php

`system("php ./somescript.php $something >/dev/null &");`

I'm new to PHP and I am deciphering someone else's code and can't figure out what this code is doing. I looked at the `system` documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) so I understand that it will execute the PHP script in `somescript.php`, and that `$something` is a parameter passed to that script...but after that I'm lost.

Also, what part of the script does `$something` get passed to? How does it know what function in `somescript.php` to call first?

Comment: "execute the PHP script in somescript.php" after than nothing, that is what it does. want to know what "*somescript.php*" does - look in the file

Comment: So what is this "./dev/null &"? And what function in the PHP script does it run first??

Comment: Redirects any output to [/dev/null](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null). In other words, a black hole.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208033/what-does-dev-null-dev-null-at-the-end-of-a-command-do

Comment: no crystal ball, what's in somescript.php ??

Comment: `>/dev/null` means it will send the output of somescript.php to nowhere; `&` means it will run in the background (kind of unnecessary in this context).

Comment: @Matt I've been looking for something like that `&` for a long time. Do you know what it's called?

Comment: And to answer your question "How does it know what function in somescript.php to call first?": It executes the file like any other PHP-file, so top to bottom (of course with all functions calls etc. that come in-between).

Comment: @arxanas `&` spelled out is "ampersand". It used to be the last letter in the English alphabet; it is a shortened way of saying "and, per se, 'and'" (w, x, y, z, and, per se, "and").

Comment: @Matt I meant in its context as a command :P. Searching for "ampersand" doesn't really help.

Comment: @Matt Not unnecessary, it's way to start daemon processes from PHP without blocking the execution of the current script. Now the code above may not actually work like this because it has not handled STDERR, and some linux flavours require you to do this as well. Personally when I'm doing this I like to do `$pid = (int) exec('nohup '.$cmd.' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!');`

Comment: @arxanas If you're wanting to execute commands in the background on *nix and completely detach them from the PHP script that started them, see my previous comment. If you want to do it on windows you have to do it via COM, and I don't know of a way to get the PID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically running the `./somescript.php` program, with `$something` as a command-line parameter.

It explicitly ignores the output by routing it to the `null` device.

And it runs it in its own shell and doesn't wait for it to finish (that's the `&` bit on the end).

I assume that `somescript.php` is a program that runs some kind of background task. It probably takes a bit of time to run, but your main program doesn't need to know about the results of that task, so it doesn't need to wait for it to finish.

[EDIT]

`$something` is passed into the program as a command-line argument. When PHP is called from the command line, the arguments are populated into the `$argv` array.

See the PHP manual for more info:

- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Comment: And how does somescript.php access that $something parameter? Is it with $argv?

Comment: @RichardDesLonde - yes, it's `$argv`. I've edited the answer to include info on that.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct about it executing the script with `$something` passed as parameter.  The `> /dev/null` is just piping the output into a black hole (i.e. suppressing it).  The `&` part launches the script in the background.

Comment: Only in case that what is in `$something` won't override all that ;)

Comment: I guess he means to say $something might have funny stuff on it, like $something = '& rm -rf / #';

Answer (score 2):

```
system("php ./somescript.php $something >/dev/null &");
```

can be split up as:

```
system(
```

This is the php function to execute a command in shell

```
system("php
```

We are asking the `php` command line interpreter to be run

```
system("php ./
```

we are asking the interpreter to look in current directory using `./`

```
system("php ./somescript.php
```

we are saying that the php file to be executed in `somescript.php`

```
system("php ./somescript.php $something
```

we are passing `$something` which is a variable in the script running `system()` as an argument into the script `somescript.php`

```
system("php ./somescript.php $something >/dev/null
```

we are saying that the output should be sent to `/dev/null` ..which basically means do not print any output on the screen. `>` is the redirection command. So `> /dev/null` means redirect output to /dev/null which is like an alias for a "null device" or simply..nothing.

```
system("php ./somescript.php $something >/dev/null &");
```

Lastly we are asking the script to be run in the background using `&` which means as soon as the script starts, control is returned back to the shell

Answer (score 1):

1 - `system`: [execution of an external program](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)  from `PHP`
2- `php ./somescript.php $something`: [`PHP cli` execution](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) of a script called `./somescript.php` with one argument being `$something`.
3 - `>/dev/null`: redirects `stdout` to `/dev/null` which means you won't see standard output, but you will still see `stderr`. [More info on output redirections](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html).   That's pure `UNIX` nothing to do with `PHP`.
4 - `&`: sends command in the background so that `PHP` execution can continue without having to wait for the external program to complete. Once again, pure `UNIX`, nothing to do with `PHP` per se. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525188/linux-running-process-background).